# How to add a private dependency to a manifest.toml file in Julia?

Tags: julia

I am trying to commit my `manifest.toml` file for a private Julia project that has a private dependancy. In the `manifest.toml` file, it has a local path to the project for the private dependancy as follows:

```
[[Private_Package]]
deps = ["AbstractTrees", "D3Trees", "DataStructures", "Distributions", "LinearAlgebra", "POMDPs", "Parameters", "Printf", "Random", "StatsBase"]
path = "/Users/logankilpatrick/.julia/dev/Private_Package"
uuid = "rand-rand-rand"
version = "0.X.0"
```

How can I keep this in my manifest file but make sure it's not a local path so I can commit to the repo?

Comment: Can you not just `]dev https://url.of/repo"` rather than `]dev path/to/repo`?

Comment: that path is what populates by default when you do `]dev https://url.of/repo"`

Comment: What about using `Pkg.add`?

Comment: @kevbonham that did the trick for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up going with `Pkg.add()` per @kevbonham suggestion. It did the trick:

```
[[Private_Package]]
deps = ["AbstractTrees", "D3Trees", "DataStructures", "Distributions", "LinearAlgebra", "POMDPs", "Parameters", "Printf", "Random", "StatsBase"]
git-tree-sha1 = "x_x_x"
repo-rev = "master"
repo-url = "https://github.com/Private_Package/Private_Package.git"
uuid = "rand-rand-rand-rand-rand"
version = "0.2.0"
```

Thank you both @DavidVarela

Comment: Yes, I think this answer is better. If you are at the point where you are testing on CI, then going through `add` is justified.